# Remove older MAMP Installation Folders from Applications

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I use MAMP Pro (4.4).
I have a number of MAMP folders in Applications using up a lot of space. 
Is it safe to delete the older ones and keep the most recent one? Therefore keeping MAMP and MAMP_2018-02-12_21-21-59 (see below screenshot) and deleting the remaining ones.
I am hoping these are just older packages and are no longer needed so I can make some space on my MacBook.

[image: list of MAMP Installation Folders]

Answer (score 2):

MAMP Support responded back to my inquiry:

> Yes, you can remove them. They are just backups in case the update
>   processes fails in any way.